# Who detached a specific SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, detach

I need to know who detached a particular database.

Is attach / detach a database logged? If so where can be the log be viewed?

Thank you

Comment: you mean to say who detached database

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @start VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @indx INT;
SELECT @current = path
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1;
SET @current = REVERSE(@current)
SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', @current)
SET @current = REVERSE(@current)
SET @start = LEFT(@current, LEN(@current) - @indx) + '\log.trc';
-- CHNAGE FILER AS NEEDED
SELECT CASE EventClass
WHEN 46 THEN 'Object:Created'
WHEN 47 THEN 'Object:Deleted'
WHEN 164 THEN 'Object:Altered'
END, DatabaseName, ObjectName, HostName, ApplicationName, LoginName, StartTime
FROM::fn_trace_gettable(@start, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN (46,47,164) AND EventSubclass = 0 AND DatabaseID <> 2
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried attaching/detaching database and i checked eventvwr,Errorlog to see any indications of who did this..It seems nothing is logged ..

The only way to track this stuff is through Audit

Comment: TheGameiswar 
This means that the Employer does not store your SQL Server this case, and should be used for Audit? But I think there is a better solution.